Ubuntu Installation Stuck on "How do you want to install Ubuntu?" Screen with Disabled Next Button
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my PC, but I keep getting stuck on the "How do you want to install Ubuntu?" screen during the installation process. The options for how to install are not appearing, and the "Next" button is disabled.

I have tried downloading the Ubuntu ISO multiple times and created a bootable USB/memory card, but every time I run into the same issue.
I downloaded the latest Ubuntu ISO three times from the official website. I created a bootable USB/memory card using different tools. I tried different USB ports and even used a memory card reader. I verified the integrity of the ISO file using sha256sum, and it matches the checksum from the official site. I attempted to install Ubuntu without an internet connection.

I can confirm this issue, which happened to me a few days ago. I also confirmed the sha256sum and flashed my 16GB disk with Disks application. During installation I got stuck at this same point as indicated in the question.

Is there any un-allocated space on the disk?  Append to your question the output of 'sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdx' . (Substitute your disk name for 'sdx') Use 'mount' to find the name of your disk. (Don't append the partition number.)

@rusty I had the same issue when creating the USB via the Disks app (using Restore Partition Image option). Creating the USB with the usb-creator-gtk tool (sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk) solved the issue.

Attention here
I just download the iso file again and made my usb bootable. and it just works i don't know how

Please make sure to create your USB with the correct tool
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk

